# How to render text in SDL2?

Tags: c, sdl-2

I'm using an `SDL_Window` and `SDL_Renderer`.

Is it possible to use `SDL_TTF` with `SDL_Render/SDL_Window`?  If so, how?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Yep, it is possible, given that you have a renderer and a window plus you don't really have any thoughts on dabbling with surfaces then you might want to mind on creating texture, here is a sample code

```
//this opens a font style and sets a size
TTF_Font* Sans = TTF_OpenFont("Sans.ttf", 24);

// this is the color in rgb format,
// maxing out all would give you the color white,
// and it will be your text's color
SDL_Color White = {255, 255, 255};

// as TTF_RenderText_Solid could only be used on
// SDL_Surface then you have to create the surface first
SDL_Surface* surfaceMessage =
    TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, "put your text here", White); 

// now you can convert it into a texture
SDL_Texture* Message = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surfaceMessage);

SDL_Rect Message_rect; //create a rect
Message_rect.x = 0;  //controls the rect's x coordinate 
Message_rect.y = 0; // controls the rect's y coordinte
Message_rect.w = 100; // controls the width of the rect
Message_rect.h = 100; // controls the height of the rect

// (0,0) is on the top left of the window/screen,
// think a rect as the text's box,
// that way it would be very simple to understand

// Now since it's a texture, you have to put RenderCopy
// in your game loop area, the area where the whole code executes

// you put the renderer's name first, the Message,
// the crop size (you can ignore this if you don't want
// to dabble with cropping), and the rect which is the size
// and coordinate of your texture
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, Message, NULL, &Message_rect);

// Don't forget to free your surface and texture
SDL_FreeSurface(surfaceMessage);
SDL_DestroyTexture(Message);
```

I tried to explain the code line by line, you don't see any window right there since I already assumed that you knew how to initialize a renderer which would give me an idea that you also know how to initialize a window, then all you need is the idea on how to initialize a texture.

Minor questions here, did your window open? was it colored black? if so then my thoughts were right, if not, then you can just ask me and I could change this code to implement the whole section which consists of a renderer and a window.

Comment: Could you please free your surface?

Comment: Message_rect.w = 100; //is the programmer supposed to know how wide his text will end up being?

Comment: you have to free both surface and texture

Comment: It's a three year old answer, I only pointed out how to create them, freeing them should be on a different topic- though they should really free it.

Comment: Can't help much since I already forgot about SDL's various syntaxes, stopped using SDL the year this was posted. To those reading this, always free/destroy/delete things you create like surface, texture, and events - since C++ does not have a garbage collector.

Comment: @engineerX You can alter it to be relative to the amount of text or window. The code shown here is the simplest one for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @engineerX you can get dimensions of rendered text with `TTF_SizeText(TTF_Font *font, const char *text, int *w, int *h)`

Comment: TTF_Font & TTF_OpenFont undefined ...would be great to explain where these come from

Comment: @fdsfdsfdsfds https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_14.html I'm not sure if it's this but are you sure that the filename (Sans.ttf in the example) is accessible?

Comment: would the correct way be: SDL_FreeSurface(surfaceMessage);
 SDL_DestroyTexture(Message);

Comment: @user1709076 to free surface and destroy texture? yep.

Comment: If this doesn't work try running `TTF_Init()` before this code.

Comment: What if I want to do not intend to use SDL_ttf library ?

Comment: Also don't forget to close the font with `TTF_CloseFont(Sans)`

Comment: You need to initialize SDL_TTF first before writing this code, call TTF_Init() before the code and TTF_Quit() when you are done.

Answer (score 26):

**SDL_ttf minimal runnable example**

[image]

Not super efficient, but easy to integrate. For efficiency see: [How to render fonts and text with SDL2 efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064904/rendering-fonts-and-text-with-sdl2-efficiently)

Kept in a separate repo than the main SDL source, but hosted on the same official server, so should be fine: http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL_ttf/

Newlines won't work. You have to work with line heights.

Compile and run:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libsdl2-dev
gcc -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -o ttf ttf.c
./ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMonoOblique.ttf
```

You must pass the path of a TTF font file to the program.

ttf.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 300
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT (WINDOW_WIDTH)

/*
- x, y: upper left corner.
- texture, rect: outputs.
*/
void get_text_and_rect(SDL_Renderer *renderer, int x, int y, char *text,
        TTF_Font *font, SDL_Texture **texture, SDL_Rect *rect) {
    int text_width;
    int text_height;
    SDL_Surface *surface;
    SDL_Color textColor = {255, 255, 255, 0};

    surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, text, textColor);
    *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    text_width = surface->w;
    text_height = surface->h;
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    rect->x = x;
    rect->y = y;
    rect->w = text_width;
    rect->h = text_height;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Rect rect1, rect2;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Texture *texture1, *texture2;
    SDL_Window *window;
    char *font_path;
    int quit;

    if (argc == 1) {
        font_path = "FreeSans.ttf";
    } else if (argc == 2) {
        font_path = argv[1];
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: too many arguments\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Inint TTF. */
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0, &window, &renderer);
    TTF_Init();
    TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFont(font_path, 24);
    if (font == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: font not found\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    get_text_and_rect(renderer, 0, 0, "hello", font, &texture1, &rect1);
    get_text_and_rect(renderer, 0, rect1.y + rect1.h, "world", font, &texture2, &rect2);

    quit = 0;
    while (!quit) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) == 1) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = 1;
            }
        }
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        /* Use TTF textures. */
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture1, NULL, &rect1);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture2, NULL, &rect2);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    /* Deinit TTF. */
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture1);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture2);
    TTF_Quit();

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/e52ed4b838e2697d8f44ab5bef3e7a170705d48e/sdl/ttf.c).

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04, SDL 2.0.4.

Answer (score 15):

Yes it is. You create a surface with the text you want and then convert it to a texture that you can render.

Some sample code from one of my projects:

```
std::string score_text = "score: " + std::to_string(score);        
SDL_Color textColor = { 255, 255, 255, 0 };
SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, score_text.c_str(), textColor);
SDL_Texture* text = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, textSurface);
int text_width = textSurface->w;
int text_height = textSurface->h;
SDL_FreeSurface(textSurface);
SDL_Rect renderQuad = { 20, win_height - 30, text_width, text_height };
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, text, NULL, &renderQuad);
SDL_DestroyTexture(text);
```

This assumes you've properly initialized SDL_ttf and loaded a font. In the example `score`is an int. The screen gets cleared and rendered to somewhere else (I didn't include that part).

For a full working example, check out the [tutorial for SDL_ttf in SDL2 at Lazy Foo](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/16_true_type_fonts/index.php).

Comment: This throws an unhandled memory exception for some reason?

Comment: @EthanWebster Oh, the code was merely meant as an (non-working) example, as it lacks important stuff to run, like the init code, error checking et cetera.

Comment: Is this efficient even if the text will change every frame?

Comment: not really compatible with my existing code that uses SDL_BlitScaled  and the font is badly rendered

Answer (score 5):

Edited to make it easier to follow along, to use `Roboto.ttf` (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) instead of `Verdana.ttf` and to add `not2qubit` suggestion. Please keep in mind that this doesn't follow any C++ class convention at all. I just wanted to be sure that this would be easy enough to copy/paste and run.

To build this you need to add the library `SDL_ttf` (https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/).

> > g++ demo.cpp -o demo -Wall -I include -lsdl2 -lsdl2_ttf

`Since there are some people struggling with more complex code, I've included my own snippet here to help some beginners like myself. This will just show a red screen with a black hello world. Don't forget to add -lsdl2 and -lsdl2_ttf on your build and include the Verdana.ttf font on the same folder.`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h> //This is an sample library not included with stock SDL2. https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release-1.2.html

const char* WINDOW_TITLE = "Hello World SDL2 + TTF";
const char* FONT_NAME = "roboto.ttf";
const int FONT_SIZE = 128;
const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720;

SDL_Window* Window; // Window created by SDL.
SDL_Renderer* Renderer; // The renderer that shows our textures.
SDL_Event WindowEvent; // Event capturer from SDL Window.
SDL_Color TextColor = { 255, 0, 0, 255}; // Red SDL color.
TTF_Font* Font; // The font to be loaded from the ttf file.
SDL_Surface* TextSurface; // The surface necessary to create the font texture.
SDL_Texture* TextTexture; // The font texture prepared for render.
SDL_Rect TextRect; // Text rectangle area with the position for the texture text.

void CreateWindow() {
    Window = SDL_CreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);
    if (!Window)
        std::cout << "There was a problem creating the window.";
    Renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(Window, -1, 0);
    if (!Renderer)
        std::cout << "There was a problem creating the renderer.";
}

void CreateText(const char* Message) {
    TTF_Init();
    TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFont(FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE);
    if (!font)
        std::cout << "Couldn't find/init open ttf font." << std::endl;
    TextSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, Message, TextColor);
    TextTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Renderer, TextSurface);
    TextRect.x = WINDOW_WIDTH - TextSurface->w * 0.5; // Center horizontaly
    TextRect.y = WINDOW_HEIGHT - TextSurface->h * 0.5; // Center verticaly
    TextRect.w = TextSurface->w;
    TextRect.h = TextSurface->h;
    // After you create the texture you can release the surface memory allocation because we actually render the texture not the surface.
    SDL_FreeSurface(TextSurface);
    TTF_Quit();
}

bool IsPollingEvent() {
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&WindowEvent)) {
        switch (WindowEvent.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT: return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void RenderText() {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255); // Make window bg black.
    SDL_RenderClear(Renderer); // Paint screen black.
    SDL_RenderCopy(Renderer, TextTexture, NULL, &TextRect); // Add text to render queue.
    SDL_RenderPresent(Renderer); // Render everything that's on the queue.
    SDL_Delay(10); // Delay to prevent CPU overhead as suggested by the user `not2qubit`
}

void ClearMemory() {
    SDL_DestroyTexture(TextTexture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(Renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(Window);
    SDL_Quit();
    std::cout << "Clear proccess done." << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    CreateWindow();
    CreateText("Hello SDL_Ttf");
    while (IsPollingEvent()) {
        RenderText();
    }
    ClearMemory();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### For Powershell on Windows

If you're trying to do this from Powershell on Windows, you'll soon find out that this is a real PITA. Until now...

I've just spent the hours to debug all the details to get this to work, when you want to insist using `Clang++` and `SDL2` to render a native Windows window with text.

There are 3 things you need to install; `LLVM, SDL2, SDL2_ttf`. Then you have to ensure your program will find your libraries, headers and fonts. This is basically summarized in the following program [here](https://gist.github.com/eabase/a531156cad6116e65aa9cefd4048769e):

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:       HelloSDL2.cpp
//  Author:     EAML
//  Date:       2021-05-16
// 
//  Description:    
//      A minimal PoC for producing a native SDL2 Windows app that can
//      be ran from either Windows Explorer or from Powershell console.
//      It's designed to use minimal command line, compiler options, 
//      and dependencies... It will display a gray window for 2 sec's.
//
//  Dependencies:
//      [1] LLVM Clang++ compiler package
//      [2] SDL2 Libraries (DLL's) and Header files (*.h)
//      [3] TTF Libraries (DLL's) and Header files (*.h)
// 
//  Notes: 
//      There is a slight variation in the bahaviour, depending on: 
//      (a) if you compile as a Windows GUI:  the text will not show.
//      (b) if you compile as a console CLI:  text will show in both terminal and/or in a 2nd new window
//      (c) You may need to use "main()" for console and "WinMain()" for GUI...
//      (c) to install on Linux, use packages:  clang, libsdl2-dev
//      (d) Someone said: #define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED ...
//
//  To Run: 
//      cp .\SDL2\lib\x64\SDL2.dll C:\Windows\.     # For SDL2
//      cp .\SDL2_ttf\lib\x64\*.dll C:\Windows\.    # For SDL2 TTF
//      cp C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf .             # Get a font...
// 
//  For a CLI version, with console output in 2nd Window:
//  # clang++.exe -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.exe -L .\SDL2\lib\x64\ -L .\SDL2_ttf\lib\x64\ -I .\SDL2_ttf\include\ -I .\SDL2\include\ -lShell32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -Wno-narrowing -Xlinker /subsystem:console
//
//  For a GUI version, without any console output:
//  # clang++.exe -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.exe -L .\SDL2\lib\x64\ -L .\SDL2_ttf\lib\x64\ -I .\SDL2_ttf\include\ -I .\SDL2\include\ -lShell32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -Wno-narrowing -Xlinker /subsystem:windows
// 
//  References:
//      [1] https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases
//      [2] http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.14-VC.zip
//      [3] https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip
//      [4] https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf.html
//      [5] http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-ttf
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include "SDL2/include/SDL.h"
#include "SDL2_ttf/include/SDL_ttf.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH    640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT   480

#define WINDOW_TITLE    "Hello SDL2!"
//#define WINDOW_TEXT   "Hello World!"

void drawText ( SDL_Surface* screen, char* string, int size, int x, int y, SDL_Color fgC, SDL_Color bgC) {
    // Remember to call TTF_Init(), TTF_Quit(), before/after using this function.
    TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf", size);
    if(!font) {
        printf("[ERROR] TTF_OpenFont() Failed with: %s\n", TTF_GetError());
        exit(2);
    }
    TTF_SetFontStyle(font, TTF_STYLE_BOLD);
    //SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, string, fgC);
    SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(font, string, fgC, bgC);
    SDL_Rect textLocation = { x, y, 0, 0 };
    SDL_BlitSurface(textSurface, NULL, screen, &textLocation);
    SDL_FreeSurface(textSurface);
    TTF_CloseFont(font);
    //printf("Oh My Goodness, an error : %s\n", TTF_GetError()); return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;                      // The window we are rendering to
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;              // The surface contained by the window
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (window == NULL) {
        printf( "Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    
    screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80)); // Set a gray background canvas
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Draw the Text
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    if(TTF_Init() == -1) {
        printf("[ERROR] TTF_Init() Failed with: %s\n", TTF_GetError());
        exit(2);
    }
    SDL_Color fgC1 = { 0xff,0xff,0xff }, bgC1 = {0x00,0x00,0xa0};                               // white text on blue background
    SDL_Color fgC2 = { 0x00,0x00,0x00 }, bgC2 = {0xff,0x00,0xff};                               // black text on magenta background
    drawText( screenSurface, (char*) "Hello World! @ (x=50, y=100)", 18,  50,100, fgC1, bgC1);  // 18 pt @ (x=100,y=150)
    drawText( screenSurface, (char*) "arial.ttf @ (x=200, y=150)",   16, 200,150, fgC2, bgC2);  // 16 pt @ (x=100,y=150)
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    TTF_Quit();
    
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Get some info...
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    SDL_version compiled;
    SDL_version linked;
    SDL_version ttfv;

    SDL_VERSION(&compiled);
    SDL_GetVersion(&linked);
    SDL_TTF_VERSION(&ttfv);
    
    printf("Compiled using SDL version  : %d.%d.%d \n", compiled.major, compiled.minor, compiled.patch);
    printf("and linked with SDL version : %d.%d.%d \n", linked.major, linked.minor, linked.patch);
    printf("and using SDL_TTF version   : %d.%d.%d \n", ttfv.major, ttfv.minor, ttfv.patch);

    SDL_Delay(3000);  // Wait 3 seconds
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

The result of running the code above is this:

[image]

---

**How to get to this point?**

1. Install [LLVM for Windows](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases):

   - Check the box for `[x] add to Windows PATH`.
2. If you didn't add LLVM to your Windows PATH, then at least add it temporarily and manually.

   - Open a Powershell and type: `$env:path += ";C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin"`
3. Install SDL2 for Windows:
   Download and extract the **SDL2** & **SDL2_ttf** runtime binaries (*.dll) and header libraries (found in [2,3])
   and put them into separate *SDL* folder(s) in the same directory as your C++ file.

   You should now have something like:

```sh
# tree --dirsfirst ./SDL2{,_ttf} -P *.h
./SDL2
├── include
│   ├── begin_code.h
│   ├── close_code.h
│   ├── SDL.h
│   ├── SDL_assert.h
...
│   ├── SDL_version.h
│   ├── SDL_video.h
│   └── SDL_vulkan.h
└── lib

./SDL2_ttf
└── include
    └── SDL_ttf.h

# tree --dirsfirst ./SDL2{,_ttf}/lib -P *.dll
./SDL2/lib
├── x64
│   └── SDL2.dll
└── x86
    └── SDL2.dll
./SDL2_ttf/lib
├── x64
│   ├── libfreetype-6.dll
│   ├── SDL2_ttf.dll
│   └── zlib1.dll
└── x86
    ├── libfreetype-6.dll
    ├── SDL2_ttf.dll
    └── zlib1.dll
```

4. Copy all the *relevant* downloaded DLL's into the `C:\Windows\`, unless you know how to make *clang++.exe* able to find them. (I wasn't able...)

```
cd C:\path\to\main.cpp
cp .\SDL2\lib\x64\SDL2.dll C:\Windows\.     # For SDL2
cp .\SDL2_ttf\lib\x64\*.dll C:\Windows\.    # For SDL2 TTF
cp C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf .             # Get a font...
```

5. Download the above SDL2 "Hello World" Windows program.

   - Use the *Minimal PoC* code from [here](https://gist.github.com/eabase/a531156cad6116e65aa9cefd4048769e).
6. Compile the program with:

```
clang++.exe -std=c++11 main2.cpp -o main.exe -L .\SDL2\lib\x64\ -L .\SDL2_ttf\lib\x64\ -I .\SDL2_ttf\include\ -I .\SDL2\include\ -lShell32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -Wno-narrowing -Xlinker /subsystem:windows
```

The order of how the libraries are placed, seem to have an importance. Make sure it's like above.

Also, notice the two different `-Xlinker` options:

```sh
/subsystem:windows   # This give you only one window but no console output
/subsystem:console   # This give you console output, but in a 2nd window when in GUI
```

To see other linker optins, use:

```sh
link.exe /link
link.exe /lib

# The most relevant are:
    /DLL
    /ENTRY:symbol
    /LIBPATH:dir
    /MACHINE:{ARM|ARM64|EBC|X64|X86}
    /SUBSYSTEM:{CONSOLE | NATIVE | POSIX | WINDOWS | WINDOWSCE |...}
    /VERBOSE
```

You are now good to go!

---

**Download References**

- 1. [LLVM](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases) Clang++ compiler package
- 2. [SDL2](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.14-VC.zip) Libraries (DLL's) and Header files (*.h)
- 3. [SDL2 TTF](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip) Libraries (DLL's) and Header files (*.h)
- 4. [Useful SDL wiki](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf.html#SEC1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to do with class:

```
// Include somewhere
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

// Do not forget to init TTF once somewhere main.cpp
if (TTF_Init()==-1) {
    printf("Failed to TTF: %s", SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
}

// Have a font instance ready
TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("assets/fonts/ugly.ttf", 72);
if (font==NULL){
    printf("Failed to load font: %s", SDL_GetError());
}

// Have a Text instance ready
// (Class file is below this code)
// Also you need to provide SDL_Renderer* renderer to init
Text* fps_tracker = new Text(renderer, font);

// Somewhere in while true
fps_tracker.setText("FPS: 232");

// Render it
fps_tracker.render();
```

Here is the class:

```cpp
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

class Text {
    SDL_Texture* texture = NULL;
    SDL_Rect position;
    TTF_Font* font;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    SDL_Color color;
    string text;
    public: 
    Text(SDL_Renderer* renderer, TTF_Font* font, string text="", int x=0, int y=0, SDL_Color color={255, 255, 255}) {
        position.x = x;
        position.y = y;
        this->color = color;
        this->font = font;
        this->renderer = renderer;
    }

    void setText(string text) {
        if (this->text==text){
            return;
        }
        this->text = text;
        SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
        SDL_Surface* surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, text.c_str(), color);
        if (surface==NULL) {
            printf("Failed to render text: %s", SDL_GetError());            
        }
        position.w = surface->w;
        position.h = surface->h;
        texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    }
    
    void render() {
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &position);
    }  

    ~Text() {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    }
    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to or can't use the SDL2 TTF library, you can easily implement it yourself with just the freetype library.

### Include freetype

```
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
```

### Create texture class

```
class texture
{
public:
    texture() : t{nullptr} {}

    texture(const texture &) = delete;
    texture &operator=(const texture &) = delete;

    texture(texture &&o) : t{o.t}
    {
        o.t = nullptr;
    }

    inline texture &operator=(texture &&o)
    {
        release();
        t = o.t;
        o.t = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    inline texture(SDL_Renderer *renderer, void *image, int width, int height, int depth, int pitch, uint32_t rmask, uint32_t gmask, uint32_t bmask, uint32_t amask) : t{nullptr}
    {
        attach_image(renderer, image, width, height, depth, pitch, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
    }

    inline void attach_image(SDL_Renderer *renderer, void *image, int width, int height, int depth, int pitch, uint32_t rmask, uint32_t gmask, uint32_t bmask, uint32_t amask)
    {
        release();

        SDL_Surface *s = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(image, width, height, depth, pitch, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);

        t = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, s);

        SDL_FreeSurface(s);
    }

    inline void draw(SDL_Renderer *renderer, const SDL_Rect *src, const SDL_Rect *dest) const
    {
        if (t)
            SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, t, src, dest, 0, nullptr, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
    }

    int width() const
    {
        if(!t) return 0;

        int w;

        SDL_QueryTexture(t, nullptr, nullptr, &w, nullptr);

        return w;
    }

    int height() const {
        if(!t) return 0;
        
        int h;

        SDL_QueryTexture(t, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, &h);

        return h;
    }

    ~texture()
    {
        release();
    }

private:
    SDL_Texture *t;

    inline void release()
    {
        if (t)
            SDL_DestroyTexture(t);
        t = nullptr;
    }
};
```

### Create glyph class

```
struct character : texture
{
    using texture::texture;
    unsigned int advance;
    int bearing_x;
    int bearing_y;
};
```

### Determine endianness and set up masks

```
#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN

#define rmask 0x000000ff
#define gmask 0x0000ff00
#define bmask 0x00ff0000
#define amask 0xff000000

#else

#define rmask 0xff000000
#define gmask 0x00ff0000
#define bmask 0x0000ff00
#define amask 0x000000ff

#endif
```

### Create converter from free type's 8bit pixel depth to 32bit for SDL2

```
void convert_8_to_32_depth(std::vector<uint32_t> &res, unsigned char *image, int width, int height)
{
    res.clear();
    res.reserve(width * height);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            if (image[y * width + x])
                res.push_back(amask);
            else
                res.push_back(0);
        }
    }
}
```

### Create font storage texture class

```
struct lib
{
    lib() = default;

    lib(SDL_Renderer *renderer, int height)
    {
        init(renderer, height);
    }

    void init(SDL_Renderer *renderer, int height)
    {
        FT_Library ft;
        if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft))
        {
            std::cout << "Can't init freetype lib\n";
        }

        FT_Face face;

        //use if you have font data in array
        // if (FT_New_Memory_Face(ft, font_array, std::size(font_array), 0, &face))
        // {
        //  std::cout << "Failed to load font\n";
        // }

        if (FT_New_Face(ft, "location/to/my/font.ttf", 0, &face))
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to load font\n";
        }

        //set size of future glyphs
        FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, height);

        std::vector<uint32_t> image;

        for (unsigned int c = 0; c < 256; ++c)
        {
            //load freetype glyph
            if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
            {
                std::cout << "failed to load glyph\n";
            }

            if (face->glyph->bitmap.width)
            {
                ///get image data that works for sdl2
                convert_8_to_32_depth(image, face->glyph->bitmap.buffer, face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows);
                chars[c].attach_image(renderer, image.data(), face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
                                      32, face->glyph->bitmap.width * sizeof(decltype(image)::value_type),
                                      rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
            }

            chars[c].bearing_x = face->glyph->bitmap_left;
            chars[c].bearing_y = face->glyph->bitmap_top;
            chars[c].advance = face->glyph->advance.x;
        }

        FT_Done_Face(face);
        FT_Done_FreeType(ft);
    }
    character chars[256];
};
```

### Print text function

```
void print_text(SDL_Renderer *renderer, int x, int y, int height, std::string_view text)
{
    static constexpr int default_height = 50;
    
    //store map of each renderer used to avoid creating more libs than neccesary
    static std::map<SDL_Renderer *, lib> l;
    const lib& ts = l.try_emplace(renderer, renderer, default_height).first->second;

    float scale = height / default_height;

    SDL_Rect dest;

    for (auto c : text)
    {

        dest.x = x + ts.chars[c].bearing_x * scale;
        dest.y = y - ts.chars[c].bearing_y * scale;

        dest.w = ts.chars[c].width() * scale;
        dest.h = ts.chars[c].height() * scale;

        ts.chars[c].draw(renderer, nullptr, &dest);

        x += (ts.chars[c].advance >> 6) * scale;
    }
}
```