# C++ Concatenating const char * with string, only const char * prints

Tags: c++, string, char

I am trying to cout a const char *

This is how I convert an int to a string and concatenate it with the const char*

```
char tempTextResult[100];
const char * tempScore = std::to_string(6).c_str();
const char * tempText = "Score: ";
strcpy(tempTextResult, tempText);
strcat(tempTextResult, tempScore);
std::cout << tempTextResult;
```

The result when printing is: Score:

Does anyone know why the 6 is not printing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reasons you don't just write `std::string textResult = std::string("Score: ") + std::to_string(6); std::cout << textResult << std::endl`?

Comment: @SimonKraemer Well, it wasn't about printing the value. I needed it to render the text in my game made with SDL.

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22886586/4181011

Answer (score 6):

As the [docs for `c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) say, "The pointer returned may be invalidated by further calls to other member functions that modify the object." This includes the destructor.

```
const char * tempScore = std::to_string(6).c_str();
```

This makes `tempScore` point to a temporary string that no longer exists. You should do this:

```
std::string tempScore = std::to_string(6);
...
strcat(tempTextResult, tempScore.c_str());
```

Here, you're calling `c_str` on a string that continues to exist.

Comment: And of course, accumulating the whole thing in a `std::string` would be even better.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Well, that's kind of impossible because SDL_ttf needs a const char * as text to render...

Comment: @OpenGLManiac You just managed to use `strcat`, which also wants a `const char*` I think you can handle `SDL_ttf`.

Answer (score 0):

You have marked this post as C++.

One possible C++ approach:  (not compiled, not tested)

```
std::string result;  // empty string
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << "Score: "  // tempText literal
      << 6;         // tempScore literal
   // at this point, the values placed into tempTextResult 
   //    are contained in ss
   result = ss.str();    // because ss goes out of scope
}
// ss contents are gone

// ...   many more lines of code

// ... now let us use that const char* captured via ss
std::cout << result.c_str() << std::endl;
//                  ^^^^^^^ - returns const char*
```

Comment: Well, I needed it to be a const char *, and this looks like a string(I don't know what stringstream is so I am not sure)

Comment: @OpenGLManiac   Ok ... I've appended the c_str() so that the result out of ss is const char*.

Comment: Added reminder that the limited scope of ss (via braces) requires that I create and capture the ss contents  to a result string .. for later use.

Comment: @OpenGLManiac --  std::stringstream can be considered a ram based stream ... simpler to use, works very much like fstream (but without open and close) and ram is somewhat faster than (most) alternatives.